# Shifting the Pitch of Non-Interleave Floats

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, audio, core-audio

I know how to shift the pitch of audio in CoreAudio but for some reason when I'm working with noninterleave data I can only shift one channel. If I try to shift both left and right channels the sound get's choppy. I can't seem to understand why it would behave this way.

I have this code in a render callback:

```
        [output.outputDataSource output:output shouldFillAudioBufferList:ioData withNumberOfFrames:inNumberFrames];//<-puts audio file frames in ioData w/ EZAudio
        int channelCount = output.outputASBD.mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved ? ioData->mNumberBuffers : ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels;
        int frameSize = ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize / ((output.outputASBD.mBitsPerChannel/8) * channelCount);
        UInt32 frames = AEFloatConverterToFloat(_floatConverter,ioData,_floatBuffers,frameSize);
        float *left = ((float **) _floatBuffers)[0];
        float *right = ((float **) _floatBuffers)[1];
        smbPitchShift(0.5, frames, 1024, 4, 44100, left, left);
        smbPitchShift(0.5, frames, 1024, 4, 44100, right, right);//<- If I take this out the left side sounds okay. vice-versa
        AEFloatConverterFromFloat(_floatConverter, _floatBuffers, ioData, frameSize);
```

Also the pitch shift functions are here -> http://blogs.zynaptiq.com/bernsee/repo/smbPitchShift.cpp

Comment: this is not c. I have retagged it to objective-c, asuming it is objective c.

Comment: @Wimmel I figured the part that was incorrect was the C part of it and the function was c++

Comment: I don't understand the first line, either if it is c or c++.

Comment: @Wimmel Ok I'm just saying the major part that is wrong, no Objective-C developer would understand without C or C++ knowledge. I even commented about what that function did to the right of it

Comment: @Wimmel: The first line is an Object-C/C++ message-send (aka. function call).  The rest is C, although the variable prefixed with `_` are direct access to the ivars that are the storage for properties of a class.

Answer (score 0):

What's with the frameSize variable? Can you not trust inNumberFrames? Either way I would check that inNumberFrames, frameSize, and frames are all consistent for your conversions.  Your also using frameSize on your last conversion instead of frames. I'd guess your converter is at fault if both channels are affected.

Comment: Both return 4096. I'm able to shift one channel and set the second channel equal to the 1st. But that would mean playing basically mono.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the header for your pitch shifting function and it looks like the osamp argument is for over sampling between calls.  So if I'm reading that correctly that means you should either use two separate pitch shifters(one for each channel) or suffer a quality loss by changing osamp to zero.